# App Store says an app is installed, but it isn't

Tags: ios-appstore

I've installed a new primary SSD drive on my mac, now I'm trying to download a few apps that I've already installed on my previous HD, but app store keeps saying they're already installed. But they are not.

Is there a way to tell Apple's App Store that these apps are not installed?

I've already tried the solution on the thread: [App Store thinks apps are installed](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/25333/app-store-thinks-apps-are-installed), but no success.

My old HD is still connected to my MBP, but as slave. If you guys need further info, just ask.

Comment: What happens if you disconnect the old HD?

Answer (score 1):

Just fixed it. Sorry for the noise, guys.

This thread fixed it:
https://superuser.com/questions/437708/how-to-re-install-an-app-that-shows-up-in-the-appstore-as-update-instead-of-b#answer-439700

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you have connected your old hard drive to your Mac, your Mac still sees the programs on the external hard drive and knows that they are still installed. You have a couple of options:

- Delete the Mac App Store apps from your external drive and then re-download the apps to your new SSD.
- Drop the apps from your external hard drive onto your new SSD, placing them in the Applications folder.