# Phantom Update Stuck In Mac App Store

Tags: mac, mac-appstore, software-update

About a year ago I downloaded the ["<3 Sudoku Daily"](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/sudoku-daily/id408895572?mt=12) (click for MAS link) app from the Mac App Store. After a while I decided I didn't want it anymore, so I deleted it by putting the application file, in the Applications folder, into the trash and emptying the trash.

However, for almost the past year, the MAS has persistently shown an available update for the application, exactly as if it were still installed on my computer.

Things I have tried:

- Installing the update (which reinstalls the app) and then deleting it
  again.
- Deleting the app using App Zapper and Hazel to erase any
  associated files.
- Signing out of my account and signing back in.
- Contacting the developer.
- Rebuilding LaunchServices per [this other  question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/7075/how-can-i-reinstall-an-application-that-the-mac-app-store-thinks-is-installed-al).
- Reindexing Spotlight.
- Disconnected any external storage devices that could even possibly have a copy of this app installed somewhere.

This phantom update has even survived the upgrade to Mountain Lion. It didn't bother me so much at first, but now, after almost a year, I'd really, really like to get rid of this application once and for all.

Does anyone know why the MAS would think that this app is still on my Mac, or what I can do to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is more likely a problem with Spotlight. Try running the terminal command

```
mdfind "kMDItemAppStoreHasReceipt == 1"
```

to see if it is still somewhere on your machine. If the file doesn't actually exist, try [forcing Spotlight to reindex](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht2409).

Comment: I've tried both of those. Terminal does not find any applicable file, and reindexing did nothing (I did a full reindex and then a reboot, then even logged out of my Mac App Store account and back in just for good measure.)