# Which files are involved in Mac App Store update checking?

Tags: mac-appstore, software-update

I've got a phantom update notification in Mac App Store which I really want to get rid of. The notification is for AngryBirds but I don't have this app installed anywhere on my mac. The issue is pretty much like this question: [Phantom Update Stuck In Mac App Store](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/57842/phantom-update-stuck-in-mac-app-store)

I have tried to contacted Apple Support but they failed to help me solve the problem. The conclusion of Apple Support is that this really needs to be fixed locally and there's nothing to do with the push server.

So to trace the real original and make this question to be more generic, I would like to ask this way:

Which files are involved in the mechanism of update checking process of Mac App Store?

Once I get to these files, I can filter them and maybe I can delete the leftovers that causes the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly, but `/Library/Receipts/` & especially the file in there called `InstallHistory.plist` would be a good place to start