# Remove applications from Software Update

Tags: macos, mac-appstore, apple-id, software-update

I have two applications showing up in Software Update that I didn't install, don't exist anywhere on any volume attached to my computer (and never have), and I would like to remove them. When I click on the "Update" button an Apple ID I've never heard of shows up (a different ID for each application). I'd install the apps just so I can delete them, but both cost money that I'd rather not spend.

[This question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/76338/remove-application-from-app-stores-update-section) never really got a useful answer, and I couldn't find anything else relevant on Ask Different. I rebuilt the [Launch Services database](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/7075/how-can-i-reinstall-an-application-that-the-mac-app-store-thinks-is-installed-al?lq=1) but no dice.

My only guess is that some applications I have, which were obtained through a friend ;), were originally installed using these Apple IDs or are otherwise associated with them, and that info is being read by Software Update. Is there some centralized place I could edit to remove these entries? I would rather not `grep -r "random_letters@mail.ru" /Applications` if I don't have to, as it's over 32GB, but if that's the only way I'll bite the bullet and do it. I was rather hoping there'd be a `.plist` somewhere I could edit real quick...

Comment: @Borderline - sorry, maybe I wasn't clear - these apps don't exist. They've never been installed on my computer or any volumes attached to my computer, yet they are showing up in Software Update.

Comment: @MattDMo Can you please run the `grep` and report back with the result? The possible answers will differ very much depending on whether you have or have not installed the applications and it will improve answer quality if people don't have to guess.

Comment: Why the -1 vote?

Comment: @patrix - I ran `grep -n -R -s -e asdfff2011 *` (`asdfff2011` being the first part of one of the email addresses) in `/Applications` and `/Library` with no results. The same search in `~/Library` has been running for several days with no results, I think it's stuck in an infinite loop or something. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Somebody asked about it on Apple Discussion Groups [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4144504?start=0&tstart=0). The answer is:

For the software update you would like to hide - make sure the full description of the update is shown - click "More..." if needed to show the full description

Right click on the update window.  Select "Hide update"

This will hide the update and it will not show in the App Store Updates Window or counted on the dock icon.

To restore - select "Show all software updates.." which is now shown in the App store "Store" menu.  Then "Reload Page" from the Store menu.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, no context menu appears anywhere :(

Answer (score 1):

Try the `--ignore` option of `softwareupdate`. In Terminal.app do: `sudo softwareupdate -l` to see the list of the available updates (and check the exact names of the applications in question) and then`sudo softwareupdate --ignore application_name1 application_name2`.

`man softwareupdate` should give you more info and examples.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, `sudo softwareupdate -l` returns "No new software available" yet after a clean restart the App Store icon in my dock is still showing that 2 updates are available...

Comment: open your apple id profile and click rest

Comment: @Borderline - there's nothing wrong with my Apple ID, and resetting my warnings won't do anything. The problem is with the App Store/Software Update program thinking I have something installed (under a **different** Apple ID) when I don't.